# How to match lines in a numbered list with a regex

Tags: regex

I want to search for all lines that:

- start with a numeric-repeat (one or several times)
- this numeric-repeat is not followed by dot and a whitespace character
- either a single dot after the numeric-repeat or a letter is okay

#### Given Lines

```
1. TEST 1 : DataLogFile
11. TEST 2 : Inter Citro File
111. TEST 3 : Inter Citro File
111.TEST4 : Match this
111TEST4 : Match this
```

#### Expected Result

Should only match last 2 lines

```
111.TEST4 : Match this
111TEST4 : Match this
```

### 1. Regex

I try with regex `^[0-9]+(?!. ).*` to match only the last row because there is no whitespace character after the dot.

Tested in [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TK7kHY/1)

#### 1. Actual Result

Matched 4 last lines

```
11. TEST 2 : Inter Citro File
111. TEST 3 : Inter Citro File
111.TEST4 : Match this
111TEST4 : Match this
```

### 2. Regex like answered

When I try the SaSkY first response `^\d+\.\S.*`,
it will only match lines that have digits, then dot, then no blank, then characters. See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BCv8UY/1)

But for input without a dot after digits it will not match.
Although expected to match also `111TEST4 : Match this`.

Comment: Can you make it possessive? `^[0-9]++(?!. ).*` for example. You are currenlty allowing backtracking. Another way could maybe to assert no whitespace is right after the dot? `^[0-9]+\.\S.*`

Comment: it would still match my 1st suggestion right?

Comment: Can you give some context, to understand the purpose of desired matches, please: What is the reason for the optional dot allowed? Is it to filter out some wrongly-formatted [_numbered list_ items](https://www.stylemanual.gov.au/structuring-content/lists#write_numbered_lists_if_the_order_is_critical) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
^\d+(?:\.\S|[A-Za-z]).*
```

- `^` start of the line.
- `\d+` one or more digits.
- `(?:\.\S|[A-Za-z])` non-capturing group:

  - `\.` a literal dot `.`.
  - `\S` any character except a whitespace character.
  - `|` OR.
  - `[A-Za-z]` a letter.
- `.*` zero or more characters.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JJMfqG/1)

Comment: @JvdV nice catch, I replaced it

Comment: It is necessary to have the dot too after the digits when I delete the dot as 111TEST4: Match this it will not match.

Comment: The non-capturing group containing alternative `(?:\.\S|[A-Z])` seems very complex. Only to match non-alpha after the dot, like `1.!`. We should have aksed @ACHRAF: What about lowercase? See [my simple answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75031022/5730279).

Comment: @hc_dev I think it is not that complex as it contains simple patterns, I saw your answer  , it is a simple and good solution but it ignores things like `1.@` , `1.2`. @ACHRAF mentioned  that `after there is no dot and a whitespace character`.

Comment: @hc_dev I updated the answer to allow small letters, thank you for reminding me

Comment: @ACHRAF The regex pattern was updated and now it allows small letters.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
^(\d)\1*+(?!\.?\s+).*$
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/9cvGTK/1)

---

Or if you want just a number at the beginning (not repeating numbers such as `111`):

```
^\d++(?!\.?\s+).*$
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have stated your expectations clearly before asking.

If you like to

- match: any "identifier" or word that is either prefixed with a number (e.g. `1Hello`) or is prefixed with an ordinal (e.g. `2.World`)
- But not: a phrase containing space like in a [numbered list entry](https://www.stylemanual.gov.au/structuring-content/lists#write_numbered_lists_if_the_order_is_critical) (e.g. `1. Hello`

#### Simple regex sequentially built

Then `^\d+\.?[a-zA-Z].*`

Matches:

```
111.TEST4 : Match this
111TEST5: Match this
111test6: Match this
```

But not those numbered-list items having separating spaces inside.
It also does not match anything starting with a letter.
Those do not match:

```
1. TEST 1 : DataLogFile
11. TEST 2 : Inter Citro File
111. TEST 3 : Inter Citro File
test7: should not match
```

️ So you can apply this regex on lines to **filter for poorly formatted numbered-list entries**.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gaMmsh/1)

#### Explained the sequence

1. `^` begin of line
2. `\d+` at least one or more digits (a number)
3. `\.?` an optional dot (raw dots need to be escaped by backslash!)
4. `[a-zA-Z]` any alphabetic letter from the range (lower or uppercase)
5. `.*` anything else (here the unescaped dot has special meaning "any character")